# ApexCharts, tooltip disappear when updateSeries is executed

Tags: tooltip, apexcharts

I have been built a page with ApexCharts that generates a bar graph with data update on time basis via AJAX routine. The only issue I faced out is that the tooltip disappears when the updateSeries method is fired up.

I searched on GitHub in the ApexCharts folder getting no idea on how to fix this.

According to yours experiences, could be a "work around" solution?
Like if the mouse pointer is in the graph, don't execute the updateSeries or execute updateSeries and force tooltip visualization by a JavaScript routine, or something like that?

Thank you.